# What's the password of an SSH private key?

Tags: ssh, python

I've never seen this window when doing ssh over the terminal, but now I'm using a python script that does ssh over the `paramiko` python module and I'm asked to provide a password (that I don't remember setting) in order to unlock the private key `username@hostname`. I tried my root password but it won't work.

The entire window says:

> Enter password to unlock the private key
>
> An application wants access to the private key `'user@host'` , but
>   it's locked

What is this password? I've never needed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to this [SO Q&A - How to ssh connect through python Paramiko with public key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8382847/how-to-ssh-connect-through-python-paramiko-with-public-key)

`paramiko` uses OpenSSH format keys. and it expect to get encrypted key as input so you also need to decrypt the key first.

- [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25312358/5088142) you can see how to use `putty` in order to convert your PGP key into OpenSSH key format:

  > To create a valid DSA format private key supported by Paramiko in
  >   Puttygen. Click on Conversions then Export OpenSSH Key
- [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8417181/5088142) you can find simple python script which uses the key and `paramiko`.

Comment: Thanks! I also discovered that ssh.connect(ip,port=port,username=username,password=password,allow_agent=False,look_for_keys=False) will work. Those flags will tell it to stop

Answer (score 7):

This is your SSH private key's password.

When you created your SSH key, you may have been queried to enter a password used to encrypt it and keep it secure.

Usually, when you SSH into a server using this private key, the SSH daemon retrieves the decryption password from your keychain, where it's usually stored. Because you're using something that doesn't directly use the SSH daemon, it's likely that it wants you to re-authenticate for security purposes.

If you don't remember your password, it will be stored in your system keychain. To read this, simply go into your "Passwords and Keys" program. From there, go to the `login` keychain. Look for the entry for "Unlock Password for user@host". Your password will be there.

Comment: But the strange thing is that I didn't specify any private key in my code, it was supposed to connect using only password

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs The private key is (by default) read from `~/.ssh/id_rsa` on most systems. When SSH connects to a server, it will attempt to go through key-based authentication and *then* fall back to password. Ideally, you'd just use key-based authentication because passwords over SSH is *really* insecure.

Comment: What's the `"Passwords and Keys" program`?

Answer (score 4):

Enter the "pass phrase" that you entered when generating the key.

Comment: passphrasethat should be the correct answer because it is applicable to all situation, not only to paramiko. I ran into the same issue trough aws-cognito connection. And solved with my `passphrase` created during the `ssh-keygen` process